# Provide Flux endpoint in Spring MVC application (PDF download)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-webflux

I have a Spring Boot 3.1 MVC application (Tomcat) where I need to add one endpoint which returns a PDF. This PDF itself is fetched from an internal HTTP server. The URL of the PDF I have to read from the DB.

**Now I want to provide the PDF with Flux<> and avoid to buffer the complete file in memory before returning it from my controller. Is this possible - and how?**

I already tried this:

Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

---

WebClient Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig {
    @Value("${internal-server.url}")
    private String baseUrl;

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient(WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder) {
        return webClientBuilder.baseUrl(baseUrl).build();
    }
}
```

---

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{id}/download-flux", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public Flux<DataBuffer> downloadPdf(@PathVariable final int id) {
    final Report report = reportService.getReport(id);
    return webClient.get().uri("/" + report.getPath()).retrieve().bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
}
```

or even this controller method:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/{id}/download-flux", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public Mono<ResponseEntity<Flux<DataBuffer>>> downloadPdf(@PathVariable final int id) {
    final Report report = reportService.getReport(id);
    return webClient.get()
                    .uri("/" + report.getPath())
                    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                    .exchange()
                    .map(response -> response.bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class))
                    .map(ResponseEntity::ok);
}
```

But I always end up in getting this error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$CollectedValuesList] with preset Content-Type 'null'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:194)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:78)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
```

What could I do? I know, my application is still a MVC application - which is good. But shouldn't it be possible to provide single flux endpoints?

Comment: You can return a stream of bytes without WebFlux using `StreamingResponseBody`. Alternatively, setting the response content type to `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` might fix the exception you've mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

For MVC it would be wiser to use void return that way no need to put any converter in. This way code will work faster, example like below

```java
@SneakyThrows
@GetMapping(path = "/download2", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public void downloadPdf2(HttpServletResponse response) {
    log.info("returning flux...");
    Flux<DataBuffer> flux = webClient.get().uri("https://files.testfile.org/PDF/100MB-TESTFILE.ORG.pdf")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(DataBuffer.class);
    DataBufferUtils
            .write(flux, response.getOutputStream())
            .map(DataBufferUtils::release)
            .blockLast();
}

@SneakyThrows
@GetMapping(path = "/download3", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public void downloadPdf3(HttpServletResponse response) {
    URL url = new URL("https://files.testfile.org/PDF/100MB-TESTFILE.ORG.pdf");
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    copyLarge(is, response.getOutputStream());
}

public static long copyLarge(final InputStream input, final OutputStream output)
        throws IOException {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024 * 1024];
    long count = 0;
    int n = 0;
    while (-1 != (n = input.read(buffer))) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, n);
        if (count % 50 == 0) {
            output.flush();
            log.info("flushed");
        }
        count += n;
    }
    output.flush();
    return count;
}
```

I tried with **flush** but performance was same with IOUtils.copyLarge. Here is [running example](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/flux-tomcat). I did some performance tests btw

```bash
downloadPdf3(HttpServletResponse) executed in 8013ms
downloadPdf2(HttpServletResponse) executed in 9477ms
```

looks like old URLConnection works in 8 seconds and flux in 9 seconds. In my local.

---

I suggest to move to netty, hopefully with spring structure it wont be a big problem. And only WebFlux example below

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/download-flux", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public Flux<byte[]> downloadPdf() {
    log.info("returning flux...");
    return webClient.get().uri("https://files.testfile.org/PDF/10MB-TESTFILE.ORG.pdf")
            .retrieve()
            .bodyToFlux(byte[].class);
}
```

[here](https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/flux-file) is running example. below how it looks
[image: local example look]

Answer (score -1):

The error you're encountering (HttpMessageNotWritableException) typically indicates that Spring is unable to find a suitable message converter for the response object being returned from your controller method. This happens because the Flux returned from your controller does not have a compatible converter to convert it into an HTTP response.

To provide a PDF as a Flux without buffering the complete file in memory, you need to ensure that you have a suitable message converter registered in your Spring application to handle this scenario.

What you can do is 1. Create a Custom MessageConverter and 2. Register the Custom MessageConverter

Here's a basic example:

```
import org.springframework.core.ResolvableType;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ReactiveHttpOutputMessage;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException;
import org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageWriter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class PdfFluxMessageWriter implements HttpMessageWriter<Flux<DataBuffer>> {

    @Override
    public List<MediaType> getWritableMediaTypes() {
        return List.of(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canWrite(ResolvableType resolvableType, MediaType mediaType) {
        return resolvableType.getRawClass() == Flux.class && mediaType.isCompatibleWith(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> write(Publisher<? extends Flux<DataBuffer>> publisher, ResolvableType resolvableType, MediaType mediaType, ReactiveHttpOutputMessage reactiveHttpOutputMessage, Map<String, Object> map) {
        Flux<DataBuffer> flux = Flux.from((Publisher<? extends Flux<DataBuffer>>) publisher);
        return reactiveHttpOutputMessage.writeWith(flux);
    }
}
```

`PdfFluxMessageWriter` is a custom `HttpMessageWriter` specifically for `Flux<DataBuffer>` that writes the data buffers directly to the HTTP response output message.

After implementing the custom message converter, make sure it's registered in your Spring application context. Spring should automatically detect and use it for converting `Flux<DataBuffer>` responses into HTTP responses.

with this you should be able to return a `Flux<DataBuffer>` from your controller method without encountering any exception.